Using sampleRegions in Google Earth Engine when combining Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 datasets
I'm trying to perform classification in Google Earth Engine using Sentinel-1, Sentinel-2, and SRTM datasets. When using only Sentinel-1, the sampleRegions function works perfectly, but when I add Sentinel-2 data, the sampleRegions returns 0 features, so there's no data for the training sample.
I checked the Sentinel-2 dataset, and it works fine in other regions. I'm unsure why it's causing issues in my specific region.
What might be going wrong?
I also try to reduce the bands in Sentinel-2, but still doesn't work.
Here’s the relevant part of the script:
//load the Dataset
//Sentinel 1
var S1_dry = ee.Image('users/ghgactions/S1_Processed_Data_Dry_Season_Landscape');
var S1_wet = ee.Image('users/ghgactions/S1_Processed_Data_Wet_Season_Landscape');
var S1_non = ee.Image('users/ghgactions/S1_Processed_Data_No_Season_Landscape');
//Sentinel 2
var S2_dry = ee.Image('projects/ee-ghgactions/assets/S2_Processed_Data_Dry_Season_10_v4');
var S2_wet = ee.Image('projects/ee-ghgactions/assets/S2_Processed_Data_Wet_Season_10_v4');
var S2_non = ee.Image('projects/ee-ghgactions/assets/S2_Processed_Data_No_Season_10_v4');
//SRTM
var srtm = ee.Image('projects/ee-ghgactions/assets/Processed_Data_SRTM_AOI_Landscape');
//combine data set
var S1_S2_dry = S1_dry.addBands(S2_dry);
var S1_S2_wet = S1_wet.addBands(S2_wet);
var S1_S2_non = S1_non.addBands(S2_non);

var all_data_dry = S1_S2_dry.addBands(srtm);
var all_data_wet = S1_S2_wet.addBands(srtm);
var all_data_non = S1_S2_non.addBands(srtm);

var trainingPoints = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-ghgactions/assets/All_Training_Sample_merge_v8');

var bands = [
   'VV',
   'VH',
   'VVrVH',
   'NDPI',
   //'B1',
   'B2',
   'B3',
   'B4',
   'B5',
   'B6',
   'B7',
   'B8',
   'B8A',
   'B9',
   'B11',
   'B12',
   'NDVI',
   'MNDWI',
   'brightness',
   'greenness',
   'wetness',
   'elevation',
  ];//, 'cover_code'];

// Function to split data into training and validation
function splitData(points, splitRatio) {
  var withRandom = points.randomColumn('random');
  var trainingPoints = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', splitRatio));
  var validationPoints = withRandom.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', splitRatio));
  return {
    training: trainingPoints,
    validation: validationPoints
  };
}

// Function to train and classify data
function trainAndClassify(image, season) {
  var dataSplit = splitData(trainingPoints.filter(ee.Filter.neq('LC_ID', null)), 0.7);
  
  // Debugging: Print training and validation points
  print('Training points (' + season + '):', dataSplit.training);
  print('Validation points (' + season + '):', dataSplit.validation);
  
  // Sample regions for training
  var training = image.sampleRegions({
    collection: dataSplit.training,
    properties: ['LC_ID'],
    scale: 30
  });
  
  // Debugging: Print sampled training data
  print('Sampled training data (' + season + '):', training);
  
  // Check if training data is not empty
  var trainingSize = training.size().getInfo();
  if (trainingSize === 0) {
    print('No valid training data found for season:', season);
    return;
  }
  
  // Sample regions for validation
  var validation = image.sampleRegions({
    collection: dataSplit.validation,
    properties: ['LC_ID'],
    scale: 30,
    tileScale: 8,
    geometries: true
  });

  var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(1000).train({
    features: training,
    classProperty: 'LC_ID',
    inputProperties: bands
  });

  var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);

  var validated = validation.classify(classifier);
  var validationAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('LC_ID', 'classification');

  print('Validation error matrix (' + season + '): ', validationAccuracy);
  print('Validation overall accuracy (' + season + '): ', validationAccuracy.accuracy());
  print('Validation kappa coefficient (' + season + '): ', validationAccuracy.kappa());

  Map.addLayer(classified, {min: 0, max: 9, palette: ['blue', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'brown', 'orange', 'black', 'pink']}, 'Classified (' + season + ')');

  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: classified,
    description: 'classified_image_' + season,
    scale: 30,
    region: aoi,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
}

// Classify and export results for each season
trainAndClassify(all_data_dry, 'dry');
trainAndClassify(all_data_wet, 'wet');
trainAndClassify(all_data_non, 'no_season');
//trainAndClassify(all_data_combined, 'combined');

Map.addLayer(trainingPoints, {}, 'Training Points');


//print('Image bounds:', image.geometry().bounds());
print('Training points bounds:', trainingPoints.geometry());//.bounds());



Map.centerObject(trainingPoints, 10);


The MSK_CLASSI.* bands are masked out, causing sampleRegions() to return an empty collection. Exclude these bands and you should be fine.
A quick hack to get rid of it would be this:
function trainAndClassify(image, season) {
  image = image.select(
    image.bandNames().filter(ee.Filter.stringStartsWith('item', 'MSK_CLASSI').not())
  )
  ...
}

https://code.earthengine.google.com/29a6ec2faf3e9196fcbe2d19dea9d760
